# I want to make date range picker with only Year and month picker

Tags: javascript, angular, select, angular-material, datepicker

I need a date range picker with only a year and month picker with Angular Material, but there is only a data range picker with MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY format. I want MM/YYYY – MM/YYYY format date range picker.

its ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatDatepicker} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import * as _moment from 'moment';
import {default as _rollupMoment, Moment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

/** @title Datepicker emulating a Year and month picker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-views-selection-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-views-selection-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-views-selection-example.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerViewsSelectionExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());

  setMonthAndYear(normalizedMonthAndYear: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value!;
    ctrlValue.month(normalizedMonthAndYear.month());
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedMonthAndYear.year());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
    datepicker.close();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Month and Year</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-hint>MM/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp
                  startView="multi-year"
                  (monthSelected)="setMonthAndYear($event, dp)"
                  panelClass="example-month-picker">
  </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I don't have mind how to make it range picker

Comment: Please add the code here what you tried and what's not working

Comment: This question is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66711984/angular-material-date-picker-range-but-only-choosing-year-and-month?rq=3

Answer (score 0):

You will find an example of month/year picker here
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-views-selection

you can combine it with a range picker

Comment: I tried, but i could not combine

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of work and some formatting it is possible. We need to implement `MY_FORMATS` to format selected date to `MM/YYYY`. And on  `(monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)"` we close datepicker `datepicker.close();` to hide the day picker view.

[image]

```js
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-views-selection-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-views-selection-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-views-selection-example.css'],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerViewsSelectionExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());

  chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedYear.year());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
  }

  chosenMonthHandler(normalizedMonth: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.month(normalizedMonth.month());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
    datepicker.close();
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-un1hfx?file=app%2Fdatepicker-views-selection-example.ts

Inspired by: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-views-selection

Comment: Thanks for ur time, but I need a date range picker. it just picks 1 date